# VM hangs when mounting a (full) partition

Tags: ubuntu, mount, partition, virtual-machine, proxmox

First of all, I should say I'm a beginner regarding these matters, so please bear with me for a moment. Thank you.

My company accidentally fill one RAIDZ partition (named **sdb1**) up to 100% of its capacity some days ago causing the VM in which such partition was originally mounted to go unresponsive.
We stopped and then started the VM succesfully, but the partition is now unmounted as it is absent in `df` (see image below).

[image]

When checking with `lsblk` I can see the disk and its partition without a mount point indeed (**sdb/sdb1**):

[image]

The problem is that when I try to mount the partition from the console using the typical `mount /dev/sdb1 <directory>`, the terminal hangs indefinitely, and when checking it out in the proxmox VE dashboard the VM appears with a warning icon indicating io-error, although apparently the VM is still running as indicated in the Status flag (I don't know why it says that, because it effectively goes unresponsive). The figure below shows the specific error.
[image]

I assume the problem comes from the lack of any free space in the partition, so, do you have any ideas about how can I proceed without losing the data? I have searched and searched for solutions and had no luck yet... The fact I'm only a begginer does not help at all, to be honest.

I'd be very grateful for any insight into this. Thank you very much in advance for your time!

Comment: A 100% full filesystem won't prevent **on linux level** a disk from mounting. I don't know about promox, but in vmware this is cause by a snapshot filling  the datastore. have you some kind of snapshot (e.g. temporary copies if disk) running ? manualy or through backup ?

Comment: @Archemar thanks for the interest! I don't have any snapshot running at the moment as far as I know. I'll mention that the partition got full when someone uploaded too many files via ftp, causing the VM to hang.